# when i click the exit button it keep looping

Tags: android

I have an issue here
when I click on the exit button on my android app which I debug it with my Samsung Note 3. it will looping from the start of the app instead of exiting it to the main screen of my note 3

below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        Button start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        Button exit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                /** start game */
                startLoop();

            }
            });

        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                onDestory();
            }
        });

    }

    public void startLoop(){
        Intent game = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
        startActivity(game);

    }

    protected void onDestory(){
        int pid=android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handle my game...

GameWorld.java (or something else) need to take controle over the game state

```
public void pauseThread() {
        gameLoop.setKeepPlaying(false);
}
```

GameLoop.java

```
// method for accessing the game logic
public void setKeepPlaying(boolean run) {
        keepPlaying = run;
}
```

and the loop itself:

```
/** MAIN GAME LOOP */
    while (keepPlaying) {

    [...]
}
```

btw: driven is this loop by a `Thread`

---

**EDIT:** example which part onDestroy takes in Android....

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "***onDestroy()***");

        disableKeepScreenOn(getWindow(), TAG);

        unregisterReceiverAndStopServices();

        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        nManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_GENERAL);

        super.onDestroy();

    }
```

And here is a Menu, which provides one entry to close the application...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    [...]
    case (OPM_EXIT):
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        return true;

    default:
        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: hi guys
thanks for the help

i am currently new to android programming 

could someone enlighten me on what is the difference between onDestory(); 
and finsih(); which was mention?

from what i have read
onDestory(); should close all the thread and release all the resource that it was
using for the app which is what i want

Comment: to call finish() will result in onDestroy() -> your app gets closed.. That is not correct at all - maybe a service, a alarm or something else will stay active in background. If you set up one of these mechanisms, onDestroy is a good place to get rid of them.. Keep in mind that onDestroy() is a function where you can say "good-night" to all the stuff your app will not need anymore (e.g. "keep screen on"-functionality). Hope it helped ;)

Comment: That was what I want to always use onDestory(); for all the app I write so that I will fully say bye bye to them and to release back all the resource. but now on my current app. when I click on the exit button which is assigned to the onDestory(); it just loop back to the start of the program.

Comment: Hehe, and thats the issue.. you shouldn't call onDestroy() you never should do this I guess... use finish() to call this function and just nest your code for clean-up there.

Comment: So you are saying i should nv use onDestory until the user not longer want to use the app?

Comment: you shouldn't type "onDestroy();" anywhere... you call "finish();" and your program jumps to onDestroy(){
[...]
~clean up~ like unregisterReceiver(xyz), stopService(abc) etc..
I will edit my answer and show you what I mean ;)
[...]
}

Answer (score 3):

Just call `finish()` - no need to do any of the `onDestroy()` stuff.

`finish()` will close the app for you.

Furthermore, any time you override `onDestroy()`, make sure to call `super.onDestroy()`!

Answer (score 1):

call `finish()` on your exit button's on click listener. You could also use java's `System.exit(0)`

Comment: Hi MetaSnarf 
do you happen to have a sample code for me to add in so that I could try?

Comment: 'exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
             finish();
            }
        });'

add this to your code and
thats it! :D needs upvotes :(

Comment: currently I cant vote for you as I don't have 15 rep point but one I got it will vote you up for the help you given in this thread